# Can I create a RAID 10 configuration starting with data from one HDD?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, raid, local-storage

I have one HDD with around 1TB of data on it.
I also have 3 identical empty HDDs that I would like to add to it and create a RAID 10 setup.

Is there any way to do this without first clearing out the data on the initial HDD?
Or for the next best thing, could I copy the data to two HDD striped, then clear the first one and then make a RAID 10 setup from there?

I am running Windows 10, but any suggestion using Linux tools is also appreciated.

The motherboard is an MSI Z97S.
For clarification, the operating system is running on a different partition, an SSD - so there are no issues there.

Answer (score 0):

Any time we have changed a RAID setup, we have backed up the data, changed the RAID setup and restored the data.

You can get a large capacity USB hard drive. Back up your data, set up RAID and then restore the data.

That is the safest way to do this and prevents data loss.